# Code To Prevent YouTube From Embedding In Twitter

Tags: twitter, youtube

I am directing some of my Twitter followers to YouTube to watch videos I recommend.  I'm trying to get an idea of how many people are actually following me up on this, so I have inserted a Goo.gl shortener for them to follow.  Problem is, Twitter seems to embed the YouTube video into the actual tweet, so users are using this to go to YouTube rather than use my shortener...which is defeating the purpose.

Is there any way to get around this?  I mean some code to either get this YouTube video from embedding in my tweet?  Or perhaps some other shortener service or something I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Log into your YouTube account:

1. Visit your Video Manager.
2. Find the video you'd like to change and click **Edit**.
3. Click **Advanced Settings** under the video.
4. Uncheck the **Allow Embedding** checkbox under the "Distribution Options" section.
5. Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page.

Please note that embedding is "all or nothing".  If embedding is allowed is is allowed everywhere, and if you disable it, it is disabled everywhere.

Source: [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en)